# Classical wave equation

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wave-equation

During my study for quantum mechanics, I encountered the classical wave equation, which is stated as "$\frac{1}{v^2} \frac {\partial^2\phi}{\partial t^2}=\nabla^2\phi$".

However, when I learnt about wave equations in general, the equation that I am more familiar with is "$\frac{1}{v^2} \frac {\partial^2y}{\partial t^2}=\frac {\partial^2y}{\partial x^2}$".

So I was wondering how these two wave equations are interlinked? Is the first one just a higher dimension wave equation in comparison to the second one?

Comment: Yes. $$\nabla^2=\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x_1^2}+\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x_2^2}+\cdots+\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x_n^2}$$

Comment: @mr_e_man so am I right in saying that $\phi$ acts as the $(n+1)^{th}$ coordinate, analogous to y and x in the first equation?

Comment: $\phi$ is often a vector or a complex variable, interpreted differently from the spatial coordinates $x_k$. But they are analogous; $\phi$ could be anything, such as the height of a string above its rest position, in which case we would call it $\phi=y$.